# Terraform GCP provider version upgrade for terraform destroying and recreating BigQuery table resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am upgrading terraform gcp provider version from 3.55.0 to 4.40.0 or later, I am seeing a strange behaviour in terraform while doing terraform plan/apply on BigQuery table resources. After upgrading to version 4.40.0, terraform plan is showing to destroy and recreate few BigQuery tables. This behaviour was not seen in 3.55.0 version.

**Actual Terraform behaviour:**
There was no change to the BQ table schema or any terraform variable for BQ resource. But when terraform plan was done for existing BQ resource, it shows the table will be destroyed and new table will be created either because of the sequence of the fields changed in the schema returned by the terraform update API or due to the STRUCT data type in json schema should be changed to RECORD.

**Expected Behaviour:**
terraform plan should say 0 resource created and 0 resource destroyed. There should be no change to the existing resources.

***Terraform version:** 1.3.4*
***GCP provider version:** 4.40.0*

***main.tf***

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "bq_dataset" {
  dataset_id    = local.application
  friendly_name = local.application
  location      = "US"
  project       = var.project
  labels        = local.labels
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_table" {
  project    = var.project
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset.dataset_id
  table_id   = "bq_table"
  schema     = file("table_schema.json")
  time_partitioning {
    type  = "DAY"
    field = "_col1"
  }
  clustering = ["_col4"]
  labels     = local.labels
}
```

***table_schema.json***

```
[ {
  "description" : "Timestamp",
  "mode" : "REQUIRED",
  "name" : "_col1",
  "type" : "TIMESTAMP"
}, {
  "description" : "Unique Identifier",
  "mode" : "REQUIRED",
  "name" : "_col2",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "description" : "",
  "mode" : "REQUIRED",
  "name" : "_col3",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "description" : "",
  "mode" : "REQUIRED",
  "name" : "_col4",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "description" : "",
  "mode" : "REQUIRED",
  "name" : "col5",
  "type" : "TIMESTAMP"
}, {
  "description" : "",
  "mode" : "NULLABLE",
  "name" : "_s",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "fields" : [ {
    "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "field1",
    "type" : "STRING"
  }, {
    "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "field2",
    "type" : "STRING"
  }, {
    "fields" : [ {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field3",
      "type" : "STRING"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field4",
      "type" : "STRING"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field5",
      "type" : "INT64"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field6",
      "type" : "STRING"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field7",
      "type" : "STRING"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field8",
      "type" : "TIMESTAMP"
    }, {
      "mode" : "NULLABLE",
      "name" : "sub-field9",
      "type" : "STRING"
    } ],
    "mode" : "REPEATED",
    "name" : "sub-field10",
    "type" : "STRUCT"
  }, {
    "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "sub-field11",
    "type" : "TIMESTAMP"
  }, {
    "mode" : "NULLABLE",
    "name" : "sub-field12",
    "type" : "STRING"
  } ],
  "mode" : "NULLABLE",
  "name" : "_a",
  "type" : "STRUCT"
}, {
  "mode" : "NULLABLE",
  "name" : "_m",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "mode" : "NULLABLE",
  "name" : "abc",
  "type" : "STRING"
}, {
  "mode" : "NULLABLE",
  "name" : "def",
  "type" : "STRING"
} ]
```

***version.tf***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.40.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14"
}
```

***provider.tf***

```
provider "google" {
  region  = var.region
  project = var.project
}
```

***Debug Output***

1. In existing schema _m field comes after _a but now with new provider it is changing the sequence and hence replacing the fields with each other.

[image]

[image]

2. In another scenario when the JSON schema contains a STRUCT field, terraform plan again says 1 to be destroyed and shows that STRUCT will be replaced by RECORD.

Comment: If you are fully confident that nothing was changed other than provider version, then you likely need to file this on the provider issue tracker.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Already raised bug in github but received no response yet.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/12940
Please let know if issue can be raised at any other place.